# non-const lvalue reference to type ... cannot bind to a temporary of type

Tags: c++

I have this problem

> 83:24: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'QImage' cannot bind to a  temporary of type 'QImage'
>   cameraimplementation.h:23:34: note: passing argument to parameter 'nextImage' here

caused by this code

```
updateImageData(toQImage());
```

with

```
void updateImageData(QImage& nextImage);
QImage toQImage();
```

How can I solve this other than including a temporary variable.

```
QImage image = toQImage();
updateImageData(image);
```

Comment: why would you want to write `updateImageData(toQImage());` ? It updates an image that will be gone on the next line

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Construct a temporary image, update it, and then discard it? C++ doesn't let you, because such a thing has a substantial chance of being a mistake.

Comment: in a world where you have millions of possibilities to shoot yourself in the foot it can be confusing when you find one way that is not allowed :P

Comment: The image in the class is updated by the passed one, not the image passed to the function. Mabye `saveImageData` would be better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

The C++ standard does not allow the binding of an anonymous temporary to a reference, although some compilers allow it as an extension. (Binding to a `const` reference *is* allowed.)

Aside from the workaround you already have, if you can change the function to take `const QImage&` then that would be better.

Comment: It works. `updateImageData` creates a copy of the QImage. It is thus valid to pass it as const.